# libjpeg-turbo unrecognized option

Tags: command-line, configuration

I'm trying to compile libjpeg-turbo with hardware acceleration enabled. Whenever I run this

```
../configure CPPFLAGS=’-O3 -pipe -fPIC -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard’
```

it says

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: -pipe
```

If I remove pipe, it says -fPIC is unrecognized and so on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of `libjpeg-turbo`? Since you are setting `CPPFLAGS`, which version of the C Compiler Suite do you have?

Comment: libjpeg-turbo 1.3.0, gcc

Answer (score 2):

The command should be

---

```
../configure CFLAGS="-O3 -pipe -fPIC -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard"
```

---

so double quotes, not single inverted commas.

Answer (score 0):

Those options (`-O3 -pipe -fPIC -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard`) look like options for the C compiler, not the C preprocessor. I think you need to use

```
../configure CFLAGS=’-O3 -pipe -fPIC -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard’
```

Also try `../configure --help` and read carefully.

I am always in the same directory when I invoke `configure` - you are not. This may be superstition.

Comment: That still returns configure: error: unrecognized option: -pipe. I'm following the directions on this website http://blog.lemoneerlabs.com/3rdParty/Darling_BBB_30fps_DRAFT.html